# How to remove a context instance from the createPackageContext method?

Tags: android, classloader, android-context

How to remove a context instance from the `createPackageContext()` method ?

I used code below:

```
context = _context.createPackageContext(package, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE | Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY); 
klass = Class.forName(classpath, true, context.getClassLoader()); 
instance = klass.getMethod(FACTORY_METHOD_NAME, Context.class).invoke(klass, context);
```

I'd like to remove the "context" instance with resources and codes included the context.